# Can't load png from assets folder, filenotfoundexception?

Tags: android

I'm trying to load an image in my assets folder named "foo.png":

```
AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = assetManager.open("foo.png");
```

This works fine on my nexus 5. When I try on a galaxy nexus, I get an exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
    /images/foo.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

I don't know why on the galaxy nexus that "/images/" part is being added to the path? If I do a listing of files on both phones, they both agree:

```
String[] files = assetManager.list("");
for (String name : files) {
    Log.e(TAG, "File: [" + name + "].");
}

// prints "foo.png" on both phones.
```

Not sure why there's this difference?

Comment: Good question as to why an error is throwing...not really sure why.  Why are you using the assets folder, rather than the res/drawable for an image, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems strange.

Did you try

```
AssetManager.openFd()
```

instead?

Comment: i get incompatible type